# PDFPage setBounds is blurry and deform

Tags: swift, pdfbox, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

The page I get from page.setBounds is blurry and deform. but the actual page (even after zooming) is very clear.I want to maintain pdf quality after setBounds.

[image: Issue can be seen on image]

```
myPage.setBounds(box.bounds, for: .cropBox)
```

Comment: PDFBox is for java and it does not have a `setBounds()` method. Why the PDFBox label?